# NebulaGraph Database: how to delete the corresponding edge data according to property value

Tags: nebula-graph

Basic details are as following:

- NebulaGraph version is 3.2.1.
- Deployment way is distributed.
- Installation way is RPM.
- Disk is non-SSD.
- CPU and  memory information
  is Single node, 4core8g

Create the edge with below statement:

```
CREATE EDGE in_use(use_type int);
```

Insert the data with following statement:

```
INSERT EDGE `in_use`(`use_type`) VALUES  "39540242"->"3461347288109088971":(1) , "77025143374879"->"3462276199342145780":(2)
```

Can NebulaGraph delete edge data with `use_type=2`? If it can, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try the statement:

```
Lookup on `in_user` where in_user.user_type == 2 yield src(edge) as src, dst(edge) as dst | delete edge `in_user` $-.src->$-.dst
```